# Anomaly in van der Waals constants of noble gases

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, gas-laws, noble-gases

In van der Waals equation for a real gas, the equation is

$$\left(P + a\frac{n^2}{V^2}\right)(V - nb) = nRT$$

where $P$ is the pressure of the real gas, $n$ is the number of moles of the gas, $R$ is the ideal gas constant, $T$ is the temperature, $a$ is a constant to correct for the intermolecular forces of attraction, and $b$ is a constant to correct for the size of the molecules.

It follows that gases with large intermolecular forces have large $a$ values and gases with large molecular size have large $b$ values.

Below is a table of the $a$ and $b$ values of the <s>ideal</s> gases:

\begin{array}{ccc}
\hline
\text{gas} & a & b \\
\hline
\ce{He} & 0.0341 & 0.0237 \\
\ce{Ne} & 0.211 & 0.0171 \\
\ce{Ar} & 1.35 & 0.0322 \\
\ce{Kr} & 2.32 & 0.0398 \\
\ce{Xe} & 4.19 & 0.0511 \\
\hline
\end{array}

Why is the $b$ value for helium larger than the $b$ value for neon even though helium's atomic radius is smaller than that of neon? Does it maybe have to do with helium's small size, and thus higher electron density surrounding the nucleus, creating more repulsions with other helium atoms?

Comment: What's the source? Also did you check other sources?

Comment: This table is invalid, it lacks the temperature/pressure range in which the equation was fitted for each gas. If they used the same range for all of them, that would definitively make the results incomparable. $a$ and $b$ are *not* universal constants for each gas, and generally vdW is not a good model for any gas over a wider p/T range.

Comment: @Mithoron from the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_constants_(data_page)

Comment: @Karl Why do you say the table is invalid when almost all of the chemical data pages for van der waals constants give only "a" and "b", as exemplified here: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/non-ideal-gas-van-der-Waals-equation-constants-gas-law-d_1969.html and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_constants_(data_page) and here: http://www2.ucdsb.on.ca/tiss/stretton/database/van_der_waals_constants.html

Comment: I know, its terrible. a and b are just empiric parameters, valid for a limited p/T range. If you make the range too big, you get a bad fit and nothing makes sense, if you make it small enough, you still cannot compare between different gases. Giving vdW parameters without a T range is simply nonsense.

Comment: @Karl (1) The VDW constants are not temperature-dependent. They are determined by the critical temperature and pressure, which are fixed: ${b =  \frac{R T_c }{ 8 P_c}}$ and ${a = \frac{27 R^2 T_c^2}  {64 P_c}}$.  Thus, in the VDW equation, they truly are constants. If you replaced the VDW constants with temperature-dependent functions a(T) and b(T), then you would no longer have a VDW model. (2)@DrPepper Given the above, your question can be reframed as: "Why is $b =  \frac{R T_c }{ 8 P_c}$ larger for helium than for neon?"  To answer this, we'd need to think about why $\frac{T_c }{P_c}\sim b$

Comment: It is practically impossible to draw conclusions without some error estimates and a better idea about how the coefficients were derived. It would be a good idea to look at the CRC and the original sources. However He being He it would not surprise me if there is an odd explanation to the trend.

Comment: @DrPepper What I wrote also explains why, as you've correctly noted, all the online reference tables only give single "a" and "b" VDW values for each gas.  Contrary to what Karl wrote, those tables are *not* invalid.  Interestingly, most of the more sophisticated gas models listed at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_gas likewise use non-T-dependent consts., and instead attempt to improve accuracy w/ more sophisticated functional forms (&/or more consts.).  Two exceptions, among those listed, are Peng-Robinson, which uses a T-dependent "a" (but const. "b"), & the virial eqn.

Comment: @theorist Sorry, that is complete bullshit. You can derive a and b with that additional theorem, however this assumes that the gas behaves as an "ideal van der Waals gas". Which no real gas does. Ergo those values are basically always worse than what you would get by fitting a/b with a set of p/T values in a reasonably limited range. And a list of a/b values that does NOT say how the values were determined is just a laugh. ALL "constants" in any gas equation have a residual T dependence, because there *is no* such thing as a final, perfect gas law. Even ten parameters are not enough!

Comment: The values in the table in this post come from the CRC handbook, and that book explains that they were computed from critical constants. I side with Karl in that there is no guarantee that the vdw constants properly describe the behavior of the gases. In other words, while van der Waals gases sharing the same critical points as the noble gases have to possess the tabulated constants, this does not mean that noble gases are well described as vdw gases having that particular set of constants (except at the critical point).

Comment: @Karl You don't understand how the VDW model works, and are peddling falsehoods as result (such as when you said a non-T-dependent table of VDW constants is invalid).  Of course the VDW eqn. has serious limitations modeling real gases. Everyone knows that. That's not the issue here. The issue is why, within the constraints of the VDW model (which is a model in which, by defintion, the constants are not T-dependent, b/c they're based on critical pts.), we get an exception in the trend.   A way to understand that is to look at how the constants are derived, which is what I offered in my comment.

Comment: To put it another way, consider, ideal gas (IG) eqn, PV = n R T.   The IG model, which contains the constant "R", is an even worse model for real gases than VDW.   That doesn't mean that a table of physical constants that shows the IG R w/o a T-dependence is invalid!!   Anyone who thinks R is invalid without a T-dependence b/c the IG model is a limited model for real gases doesn't understand that model. And insisting that the VDW a and b are invalid without T-dependencies reflects the same lack of comprehension as insisting the IG R is invalid w/o a T-dependence.

Comment: There seems to be a reasonable explanation for this phenomenon here: http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/1998-02/887638249.Ch.r.html. The author concludes that polarizability will affect the b parameter, appealing to ionization potentials to explain this trend.

Comment: I'm not sure I really want to wade into this argument, but... a and b are indeed constants defined by critical parameters in the vdW model, as theorist has described. This might not describe real gases all that well, as Karl has stated, but it remains a property---indeed, a necessary property---of the model for consistency. Karl's statements make more sense for virial coefficients, where no such restriction holds and a temperature range should indeed be stated.

Answer (score 1):

### The Quantum Gases

I will venture a guess, and hopefully a rational explanation. As discussed in the comments, the van der Waals equation parameter can be derived from mathematical considerations at the critical point and can be calculated as $\displaystyle b = \frac{RT_\mathrm{crit}}{8P_\mathrm{crit}}$.

The critical temperatures of the first three entries from your table are

$$\begin{array}{cr}
\text{Gas} & T_\mathrm{crit}/\pu{K} \\ \hline
\text{He} & 5.2 \\
\text{Ne} & 44.5  \\
\text{Ar} & 150.7 
\end{array}$$

From these, I will offer hand-waving "quantum effects" as the culprit affecting the parameters of this classical equation of state. At the critical point of helium, quantum effects dominate. As things warm up to neon's critical temperature, quantum effects become less important, and by the time we hit argon's, many (if not most) quantum things can be ignored. Because the quantum effects will also scale inversely with mass, they are again important in the order: helium, neon, argon.

So I imagine because hydrogen, helium, and to some extent neon are "quantum gases"
their van der Waals equation parameters will not be directly comparable to those of "classical gases".